# How are images and icons added in Xamarin.Forms?

Tags: xaml, xamarin, xamarin.forms

This is my first time using Xamarin.Forms and I want to know how I can add an icon or an image. I tried to look it up, but it's very complicated

```
<ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             xmlns:local="clr-namespace:hello"
             x:Class="hello.MainPage">
    <StackLayout >
        <Label Text="Hello" 
               VerticalOptions="Center" 
               HorizontalOptions="Center" 
               TextColor="White"
               FontSize="30"
               FontAttributes="Italic"/>

        <Image /> I am trying to add it here
        <Icon/> I am trying to add it here

        <Label Text="Name" 
               VerticalOptions="Center" 
               HorizontalOptions="Center" 
               TextColor="White"
               Font="large"/>
        <entry placeholder="Enter your name here"/>
    </StackLayout>
</ContentPage>
```

Comment: https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/xamarin-forms/user-interface/images/

Comment: As a side note, you might consider using svg's for icons (check out link): https://github.com/luberda-molinet/FFImageLoading/tree/master/samples/ImageLoading.Forms.Sample/Shared

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set the Icon for a Page, but I do not know of an Icon control. Setting the icon for page can be done pointing to a local resource or online resource.

```
<ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
     xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
     xmlns:local="clr-namespace:hello"
     x:Class="hello.MainPage" 
     Icon="Icon.png">
```

Set show an [Image](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/xamarin-forms/user-interface/images/) you need to set the Source of the Image

```
<Image Source="waterfront.jpg" />
```

Comment: and How can I change the width and height of the image

Comment: Check out [Displaying Images](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/xamarin-forms/user-interface/images/#Displaying_Images)

Comment: You can determine the height and width y using HeightRequest and WidthRequest resp.

Comment: What do I have to do with the image before I can point to it with `Icon="Icon.png"` or `Source="waterfront.jpg"`.

Answer (score 5):

In `Xamarin.Forms` it is recommended to add images in native project's only because every platform needs different dimensions & resolutions images. So we are adding images here how we do for Android & iOS project.

**Android:**

- drawable-mdpi
- drawable-hdpi
- drawable-xhdpi
- drawable-xxhdpi

`hdpi`, `mdpi` `drawable-xhdpi` `drawable-xxhdpi` refer to the screen density in dots-per-inch.

> It’s best practice to place your app launcher icons in mipmap (not the
>   drawable- folders)

Keep in mind that in Android, all images are in different folder but with same naming convention.

Add Images in `Drawable` folder:

[image]

**iOS:**

**This method of working with images in an iOS app has been deprecated by Apple since iOS 9. You should use the *Asset Catalog* instead.**

**For more information, see [Image Sizes and Filenames](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/ios/app-fundamentals/images-icons/displaying-an-image?tabs=windows).**

For iOS project, expand the `Resources` folder and add your images here. In iOS, we follow a naming convention to differentiate our images.
If your image name is `abc.png`, for high version of this image, you may use `abc@2x.png` or `abc@3x.png` etc.

Keep in mind that in iOS, all images are in same folder but with different naming convention.

Add Images in `Resource` folder:

[image]

**UWP:**

Universal Windows Platform (UWP) - Place images in the application's root directory with Build Action: Content.

UWP image file names can be suffixed with *.scale-xxx* before the file extension, where `xxx` is the percentage of scaling applied to the asset, e.g. `myimage.scale-200.png`. Images can then be referred to in code or XAML without the scale modifier, e.g. just `myimage.png`. The platform will select the nearest appropriate asset scale based on the display's current DPI.

Using Images in Shared project

```
<Image  Source="Image1"  WidthRequest="80" HeightRequest="80" ></Image>
```

Comment: Can you add the information about how to add the UWP image for completion?